# creative Ruby-way to evaluate string to one of class constants

Tags: ruby, logging, constants

As you may know Logger:Application has constants (Logger::DEBUG, Logger::WARN etc...)

My log level is a string in my config. Passing that string to my logger gives error. I'll have to override the level method to accept a string.

```
log = Logger.new($CONFIG.log.file, $CONFIG.log.freq)
log.level = $CONFIG.log.level ## << Error
#log.level = Logger::WARN ## < manually settings it as example in doc.
```

how would you set the logging level dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
log_level = 'WARN'
log.level = Logger.const_get(log_level)  #=> 2  (which is the value of Logger::WARN)
```

Be careful with your input though, as `Logger::Error` & `Logger::ERROR` are not the same thing.